# How can I transfer node and comment records from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7?

Tags: migrations

Is it possible to export particular nodes and comments in Drupal 6 and import them in Drupal 7? I do not want to copy the whole database and then upgrade it, but be able to move particular records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could look into using the [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module. Although I haven't used it myself, I know that many have been using it to move content from a Drupal 6 website into a Drupal 7 website. Be aware that it is an advanced module that has no UI (that I'm aware of). It integrates with [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) and allows you to create migration scripts and run them from the command line.